# Exception when save in a JPA definition with Spring Boot + Spring data JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a problem with a JPA definition using Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA, I have defined the next entities:

CommerceCnae.java

```
@Entity
public class CommerceCnae implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5071526484444404982L;

    @Id
    private String name;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "commerce", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<AddressCnae> addresses;

    @OneToMany( mappedBy = "commerceCategory", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<CategoryCnae> categories;

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     *            the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the addresses
     */
    public List<AddressCnae> getAddresses() {
        return addresses;
    }

    /**
     * @param addresses
     *            the addresses to set
     */
    public void setAddresses(List<AddressCnae> addresses) {
        this.addresses = addresses;
    }

    /**
     * @return the categories
     */
    public List<CategoryCnae> getCategories() {
        return categories;
    }

    /**
     * @param categories
     *            the categories to set
     */
    public void setCategories(List<CategoryCnae> categories) {
        this.categories = categories;
    }

}
```

CategoryCnae.java

```
@Entity
public class CategoryCnae implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3889422753757007724L;
    @Id
    private String id;
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private CommerceCnae commerceCategory;

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @param id
     *            the id to set
     */
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the description
     */
    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    /**
     * @param description
     *            the description to set
     */
    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    /**
     * @return the commerceCategory
     */
    public CommerceCnae getCommerceCategory() {
        return commerceCategory;
    }

    /**
     * @param commerceCategory
     *            the commerceCategory to set
     */
    public void setCommerceCategory(CommerceCnae commerceCategory) {
        this.commerceCategory = commerceCategory;
    }

}
```

AddressCnae.java

```
@Entity
public class AddressCnae implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7387779987115612860L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long addressCnaeId = 0;

    private String city;
    private String address;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private CommerceCnae commerce;

    /**
     * @return the city
     */
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    /**
     * @param city
     *            the city to set
     */
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    /**
     * @return the address
     */
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    /**
     * @param address
     *            the address to set
     */
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if ((obj instanceof AddressCnae)) {
            AddressCnae addressCnaeObj = (AddressCnae) obj;
            return (addressCnaeObj.getAddress().equals(this.getAddress()) && addressCnaeObj.getCity().equals(this.city));
        } else {
            return false;

        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + this.address.hashCode() + this.city.hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * @return the commerce
     */
    public CommerceCnae getCommerce() {
        return commerce;
    }

    /**
     * @param commerce
     *            the commerce to set
     */
    public void setCommerce(CommerceCnae commerce) {
        this.commerce = commerce;
    }

    /**
     * @return the addressCnaeId
     */
    public long getAddressCnaeId() {
        return addressCnaeId;
    }

    /**
     * @param addressCnaeId
     *            the addressCnaeId to set
     */
    public void setAddressCnaeId(long addressCnaeId) {
        this.addressCnaeId = addressCnaeId;
    }

}
```

And here is my repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CommerceRepository extends JpaRepository<CommerceCnae, String> {

}
```

But when save I have the next exception:

```
2015-04-08 11:22:31.320 DEBUG 18145 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : could not execute statement [n/a]

java.sql.SQLException: Field 'commerce' doesn't have a default value
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:996)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3887)
```

Is a bi dirrectional relation, and my configuration is the next:

```
#DATASOURCE CONFIGURATION

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://XXXXX/somthing
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=XXXXX
spring.datasource.password=XXXXX
spring.datasource.continueOnError=false
spring.datasource.max-active=5

#JPA CONFIGURATION
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop
```

What is wrong?

Thanks for your help!

Edit:

Data to save:

```
{  
   "@type":"es.domain.jpa.commerce.CommerceCnae",
   "name":"LAICOS S A",
   "addresses":{  
      "@type":"java.util.ArrayList",
      "@items":[  
         {  
            "@type":"es.domain.jpa.commerce.AddressCnae",
            "addressCnaeId":0,
            "city":"31200 ESTELLA - ",
            "address":"CL WITHOUTNUMBER 00033",
            "commerce":null
         }
      ]
   },
   "categories":{  
      "@type":"java.util.ArrayList",
      "@items":[  
         {  
            "@type":"es.domain.jpa.commerce.CategoryCnae",
            "id":"6441",
            "description":"OTHER DESCRIPTION.",
            "commerceCategory":null
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I put `nullable = true` , and doesn't works. The same error.

EDIT WITH SOLVE:

The problem is in initializing, something strange happens when you put @ManyToOne or @OneToMany relations and option spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop. I deleted the database and initialize with spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update. Is solved!! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Not sure, but this is bcoz *you have specified `not null` &/or `default value` constraints in SQL script & not in POJO.* Try regenerating tables by Hibernate automatically & then check for the same. Then compare both the SQL script & u get the actual cause.

Comment: Try initializing the lists for example: `private List<AddressCnae> addresses = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: You have `nullable = false` on the `commerce` and you probably don't set any vaue...

Comment: Initializing list doesn't work, added the representation of save object in JSON.

Comment: I put  `nullable = true `, and doesn't works. The same error. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried creating tables via Hibernate ? What result u obtained from it ?

Comment: Thanks @OO7 , I have deleted all tables and it provides me another exception `org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : es.domain.jpa.commerce.AddressCnae.commerce -> es.domain.jpa.commerce.CommerceCnae; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException:object references an unsaved transient instance- save the transient instance before flushing : es.domain.jpa.commerce.AddressCnae.commerc -> es.domain.jpa.commerce.CommerceCnae` I'm working in it

Comment: This error means you are trying to save an instance of object which has one or more unsaved dependent object.

Comment: But I have defined a bidirrectional relation, I suppose when I save `CommerceCnae` the relations with `AddressCnae` and `CategoryCnae` save automatically, it is correct?

Comment: But now return me another exception: `org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save(): es.domain.jpa.commerce.CommerceCnae`, this makes me crazy :(

Comment: `CommerceCnae.name` is of type `String`. So you have to set value for it & it must be unique. Have u set value for this field ?

Comment: The problem is in initializing, something strange happens when you put `@ManyToOne` or `@OneToMany` relations and option `spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop`. I deleted the database and initialize with `spring.jpa.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update`. Is solved!! Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Check that you can read the correct data back from the DB, looking at your code I would suspect that you will not get any addresses for your commerce. See the answer bellow. Unless of course you already fixed it in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your example data and the comments they are few problems.

Your JSON data represents the CommerceCae tree that:

- has one address of id 0 and no back reference to the actual CommerceCae (commerce == null)
- has one category of id 6441 and no back referenced to the actual CommerceCae

Now in JPA configuration you set the ManyToOne relationships are handled (mappedBy) the address or category entities. So the commerce value has to be set before the persistent. The input data did not have them so you got your SQL exception as the join column had null value which was not allowed (btw you should bring the nullable=false again and regenerate the tables, it was ok at the begging you just handled the objects wrong).

So after you read your JSON data you have to fix relationships:

```
CommerceCnae c = ....
for (AddressCnae a : c.getAddresses()) a.setCommerce(c);
for (CategoryCnae cat : c.getCategories()) cat.setCommerceCategory(c);
....
EM.persist(c);
```

That would solve your `java.sql.SQLException: Field 'commerce' doesn't have a default value`

Now, in your CommerceCnae there is no ID generation strategy, so before the persisting you have to assign the ID manually. As your JSON data does not seem to have ID field, I guess it was a simple omission and you want to have ID generated by JPA so add `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` to the Commerce Id field.

Your Category class does not have ID generation strategy which is correct as your JSON data already contain the ID values.
But Your JSON data have ID for Address but you chose the id to be automatically generated by JPA in its POJO object. I don't know if it was on purpuse or just coincedence.